# How to get only first object value key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a array of object like -

```
array = [{label:"1",value:"11"},
         {label:"2",value:"22"},
         {label:"3",value:"33"},
         {label:"4",value:"44"},
        ];
```

How can I get the `value` of the first object (11)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `array[0].value`:

```js
var array = [{
    label: "1",
    value: "11"
  },
  {
    label: "2",
    value: "22"
  },
  {
    label: "3",
    value: "33"
  },
  {
    label: "4",
    value: "44"
  },
];

var firstValue = array[0].value;
console.log(firstValue);
```

You can also use destructuring like so:

```js
var array = [{
    label: "1",
    value: "11"
  },
  {
    label: "2",
    value: "22"
  },
  {
    label: "3",
    value: "33"
  },
  {
    label: "4",
    value: "44"
  },
];

var [{ value: firstValue }] = array;
console.log(firstValue);
```

Comment: Thanks actually i am fetching this list from api and so i check the length and than updated in when i receive new props.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a funky [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) by taking the object with key zero (just the first element of the array) and then the `value` property.

```js
var array = [{ label: "1", value: "11" }, { label: "2", value: "22" }, { label: "3", value: "33" }, { label: "4", value: "44" }],
    { 0: { value } } = array;
    
console.log(value);
```

Comment: I agree this is a very fancy way. But I'm just trying to imagine the face of the OP looking at this based on his question, :-). +1 for the alternative fancy way!

Answer (score 0):

Simply grab the item at the `0` index of `array`. See comments for more details:

```js
//The initial data
var array = [{
    label: "1",
    value: "11"
  },
  {
    label: "2",
    value: "22"
  },
  {
    label: "3",
    value: "33"
  },
  {
    label: "4",
    value: "44"
  },
];

//Access the item you want by it's index in the array (0-based)
var firstItem = array[0];

//Grab the "value" property from the object
var value = firstItem.value;

//Log your value
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
 var array = [{label:"1",value:"11"},
         {label:"2",value:"22"},
         {label:"3",value:"33"},
         {label:"4",value:"44"},
        ];
    console.log(array[0].value);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
String foo = array[0].value;
println foo;
```

Comment: Wrong language.

Comment: The question was tagged [java] initially